Relation between centerless groups and semidirect products
Let $H$ be a group, $G \triangleleft H$ a normal subgroup and $K \leqslant H$ a subgroup. We say $H$ to be a semidirect product of $G$ and $K$, denoted by $H= G \rtimes K$, if $H=GK$ and $G \cap K=1$. Let us recall that $Z(H)= \{ x \in H \ \vert \ \forall h \in H, hx=xh  \}$ is the center of $H$. A group $H$ is centerless if the center is trivial. My question is the following one:

If $H$ is centerless, can $H$ always be decomposed as a non-trivial semidirect product?

I can provide the following partial answers:

If $H$ is a finite centerless metaabelian group, it is proven here.
If $H=A *B$ is a free product it is proven here

Note that by non-trivial semidirect product I mean avoiding cases such as $H=G \times 1$, $H=1 \times K$, or $H=G \times K$.

Why is the first point straightforward? If $G$ is a finite nonabelian simple group, the normal subgroup $H$ must be $1$ or $G$. So it is not possible. Of course, $Z(G)=1$ then, too.

It is not straightforward as you have pointed out, it was wrong.

To answer the question stated in the OP: No, you can construct a group $H$ which is centerless (i.e. trivial center) and lacks non-trivial semidirect product decomposition. An easy example to see this with is the alternating subgroup $A_5\triangleleft S_5$...but to be a little more general, take any non-abelian simple group and you should get this contradictory outcome.
Why is this the case? That all non-abelian simple groups contradict the posed statement? Recall that simple groups are defined as the groups in which $0$ and $H$ are the only normal subgroups $\triangleleft\ H$. Since the center of a group will be normal, we know that $Z(H)=0$ because $H$ is non-abelian. Since $H\cong N\rtimes G$ will necessarily have an isomorphic copy of $N$ as a normal subgroup (by construction of semi-direct product), then $N=0$ or $H$. We are therefore left with the trivial case.

As you have mentioned simple and non-abelian groups satisfy the condition, what can we say about the non-simple case?

@Juanandete Firstly, I see that you are new to this site. If my original post was a sufficient answer, please consider marking it as "Accepted Answer". This is a strong motivator for people who contribute to this site, plus you get "+2" reputation whenever you accept an answer. Thank you. :)

@Juanandete Secondly, I have outsourced your new question via my post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4928588/non-simple-centerless-group-with-exactly-one-non-trivial-normal-subgroup. I will update you when I hear back from the community. This is a very tricky question, the uses of which I struggle to see for the moment. But hopefully we can get something soon.

@Juanandete Update: Derek Holt has given us a counter-example. Therefore, we should be able to conclude that even when excluding simple groups, your revised statement will not hold true.

Thank you very much for your time and effort! I've just accepted you answer. :)
